# MySQL FIND_IN_SET() in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have changed FIND_IN_SET() in TSQL with IN() or LIKE but it does not work. It's a very long query and I am pasting a small chunk of it.

SQL ERROR:
This error show when use IN() or LIKE()

```
SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near '>'.
```

The column feature_set is `nvarchar` and values stored like 100,101,103,104 which I supposed is a string that may cause the issue.

I have tried STRING_SPLIT() but it throws the same error and another problem is that the values in feature_set could be shuffled so it had to find from the whole string.

MYSQL query part:

```
    CASE 
         WHEN     
         FIND_IN_SET(100, vendor.feature_set) > 0 OR    
         FIND_IN_SET(101, vendor.feature_set) > 0 

    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS abc_code_enabled
```

TSQL version using IN:

```
    CASE
        WHEN 
        100 IN (vendor.feature_set) > 0         
        vendor.feature_set LIKE 101 > 0 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS abc_code_enabled
```

TSQL version using LIKE:

```
    CASE
        WHEN 
        vendor.feature_set LIKE 100 > 0         
        vendor.feature_set LIKE 101 > 0 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS abc_code_enabled
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` is a custom MySQL function. Don't expect people to know what it does. If it checks a flag in a bitfield or array though, it's a bad idea from the start. Such properties not. only can't be indexed, they break the relational model. Use a 1-to-Many or many-to-many table instead. You can store the IDs in a JSON array and check if the value exists with `OPENJSON`. It won't really be slower than  `FIND_IN_SET`. Both have to scan the entire table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use STRING_SPLIT(), it should be used like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN     
    100 IN (SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(feature_set, ',')) OR    
    101 IN (SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(feature_set, ','))

THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS abc_code_enabled
```

Comment: I just have to change it like this:
`'100' IN (select (value) as feature from STRING_SPLIT(vendor.feature_set, ',') )`

Answer (score 3):

The workaround I like to use here involves surrounding the CSV field in your table with commas on both sides, and then searching for the term, itself also surrounded by commas.  As an example, to find `100` in the `feature_set` column having the values `100,200,300`, we search for `,100,` in this:

```
,100,200,300,
```

Here is some SQL code:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM vendor
WHERE ',' + feature_set + ',' LIKE '%,100,%' OR
      ',' + feature_set + ',' LIKE '%,101,%';
```

Of course, it would be best to avoid using CSV like this in your SQL Server tables.  Instead, maintain each CSV entry on a separate row, and tie logically related values together in a second column using some kind of ID or group.

Comment: I tried this solution but in CASE expression it give me `SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near '>'.` Error. As I mention this is  big query I posted few lines over here.

Comment: ...almost for certain you're not running my query, as I have no inequality operators.  Please start with my exact answer.

Comment: *"As I mention this is big query I posted few lines over here."* I *hope* you don't mean you are using Google Bigquery thrre, @HemantKumar ; that's a different dialect to T-SQL.

Comment: @Larnu I also hope the OP is actually using TSQL, otherwise I might be in a for a `BigSurprise`.